# Sqlite - efficient select count query

Tags: sqlite, count, exists

I have a table in my database I do a Select all on:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA;
```

I want to append a column that is true or false if there's a related column in anther table. I can do it with this:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(Id) > 0 FROM TableB WHERE Id = TableA.Id) FROM TableA;
```

But I don't want to have to count EVERY row in TableB to work this out as its ineffient. I essentially want an `EXISTS` check instead of count.

How do I replace the `COUNT` with `EXISTS`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah - just realised the answer to my own question

```
SELECT *, EXISTS(SELECT Id FROM TableB WHERE Id= TableA.Id) AS DoesExist FROM TableA
```

Answer (score 1):

By using a `left join`

```
SELECT a.*, b.id is not null as condition_check
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b ON a.Id = b.Id
```

Comment: Is this more efficient than the exists?  I want to use the most efficient method :-)